# Azure does not update files on a web server (Pyramid wsgi-app)

Tags: azure, pyramid, wsgi

I have a project Pyramid Application. I store it on git and pull the branch to the server when I need update. Until now I was working on [Koding](https://koding.com) but lately decided to check out azure and it's developer's benefits.

After I've created ubuntu server virtual machine (which actually is what runs under [Koding](https://koding.com)) I've downloaded my project using git pull, but forgot to change the branch to the one I'm working on atm. So I did, but server still shows me the old page (like I didn't checkout the other branch). So I checked sftp and files show me they have been updated.

Why am I still seeing the old page?

Comment: Did you restart your app after `git checkout mybranch`?

Comment: I did restart everything there was to restart

Comment: I did `python setup.py` and it worked... whyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?

Comment: Was that the first time you had run `python setup.py develop|production` on the recently checked out branch? Could be that there are different dependencies on that branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know the reason why! (at least I think, but please. correct me if I'm wrong)

I noticed that there was .pyc file for every .py file, and those are "compiled" (bit of simplification?) python files as I understood it. And it seemed to me that they were not "compiled" on app launch. But they compiled with setup.py... edit dates suggest that.

So the reason why I didn't see the changes I did in code was that... http.server was using old "compiled" files instead of the source files! But is that normal/expected behaviour? Dunno. There are many other quetions now, but main question was answered so I mark this as answer until someone gives better answer.